# Why aren't the application permissions being added to my MS Graph token?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get a subscription created with the callRecord resource (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)

In the app registration section of the Azure portal, I've created a multi-tenant app with a client secret.  That app has permissions for application-level "CallRecords.Read.All" as well as the default delegated "User.Read".   The statuses also have a green checkbox for being granted against my organization by an admin.

I am able to get an access token with the following HTTP POST request to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token:

```
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
client_secret:<client_secret>
client_id:<client_id>
code:<code>
redirect_uri:http://localhost:3000
```

However, that token is not able to generate a subscription to my callRecord resource.  I get a response with this message: "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: Forbidden; Reason: The request is not authorized for this user or application.]"

The message suggests that the app has not been granted admin-level authorization, but in fact it has.  This used to work for me.  I'm wondering if there has been a regression on the MS Graph side.

Further, when I examine the JWT, I see that the scope is "User.Read profile openid email". There is no mention of the application-level permission (specifically, CallRecords.Read.All)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because when you use the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow), just the *Delegated permission* will take effect. So even if you grant the *Application permission*, the token you got will not include the permission.

From the doc, to call this API [`Get callRecord`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http), just the Application permission is supported.

[image]

To get the token which include the permission, your option is to use the [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow).

**Note**: You need to use `<tenant-id>` instead of `common` in this flow.

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id=xxxxxxx
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&client_secret=xxxxxxx
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

[image]

Decode the token in https://jwt.io, the `roles` includes the `CallRecords.Read.All` permission:

[image]